# "Waiting" on either a promise or regular object using native(ES6) JavaScript promises

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, terminology

I played with promises a few times a few years ago using either jQuery or Q. I'm now quite rusty and want to learn and use the new native ES6 promises.

I seem to remember one neat concept where you can "wait" on something and not care whether it's a plain object or a promise. If it's a promise the callback is called when it asynchronously completes, if it's anything else the callback is called immediately - maybe the next tick.

But I can't recall how this is done. I'm not sure if it has a name so it's proving difficult to Google for. I'm not sure if it's a standard feature across all JS promise implementations, or if it was just something only jQuery had.

What is this called? Can I still do this with native promises? Where can I read up on it?

Comment: It seems to be something to do with jQuery's `.when()` which may or may not be similar to `Promise.all()` ...

Comment: Maybe `Promise.resolve(x)`? If you give it a promise, it just returns the promise, but if you give it anything else it returns an immediately fulfilled promise with that value.

Comment: @AgentME: Ah maybe. It sounds like that's another thing that's different between jQuery promises and native. They already bent my brain a bit but the differences are bending it worse \-:

Comment: It seems that [both jQuery.when() and Promise.all()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828504) take an array whose elements can each be either a promise or a plain object/value. That's probably what I was thinking of. But as I'm still playing with it and somebody who really knows there stuff might post an answer I'm not going to answer myself yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both jQuery's `$.when()` and ES6's `Promise.all()` exhibit the behaviour you refer to. Provide a promise and the function waits for the promise to resolve, but for any other value it returns immediately.

Comment: It's worth noting that `Promise.all()` will only take an iterable object (e.g. an array), and executes each promise in the iterable at the same time. [`Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) (which is used by `Promise.all()` under the hood) is more of a direct parallel to jQuery's `$.when()` if you're calling it with only one object.

Comment: So in other words, `$.when(x)` is roughly equivalent to `Promise.resolve(x)`, and `$.when(x, y, z)` is roughly equivalent to `Promise.all([x, y, z])`.