# What are the differences between jQuery.when() and ES6's Promise.all()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I learned promises with jQuery and then didn't do much programming for a couple of years. Now I want to do some stuff using native ES6 promises.

Promises bent my head a little back then. Now with both being quite rusty on top of that and there being minor and major differences between jQuery promises, other promise libraries, and the new native JS promises, my head gets even more bent when I try to get this stuff working.

It seems like [`jQuery.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) and [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) do the same thing, but are there some important differences we should keep in mind?

Comment: Is `$` and `document.querySelectorAll` same ?

Comment: @Rayon: I thought `$` was the same as `document.querySelector` and `$$` was the same as `document.querySelectorAll` in a browser devtools console. But `$` in jQuery is the `jQuery` object.

Comment: That is what my point is! How could you compare `jQuery` with `JavaScript-Promise` ?

Comment: Then I don't get your point. You can compare anything. I'm not comparing all of jQuery to just the promises of native JS, I'm comparing one of jQuery's promise functions with one of native JS's promise functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Promise.all()` takes `Array` of `Promises` or plain `JS objects` as argument so you need to access results by index.

`jQuery.when()` takes multiple arguments which are plain `JS objects` or `jQuery Deferred`, so you can access your result by variable name.

Comment: It seems that `Promise.all()`'s array can also be either `Promise`s or plain objects. If the latter it calls `Promise.resolve()` internally. But I'm still figuring it out... \-:

Comment: Oh snap! I forgot to mention that :). I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks. That was [the problem I was trying to remember/solve](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827900) that led me to ask this question. (-: